# Python and conflicting module names

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

It seems that if a file is called `io.py` and it imports `scipy.ndimage`, the latter somehow ends up failing to find its own submodule, also called `io`:

```
$ echo "import scipy.ndimage" > io.py
$ python io.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "io.py", line 1, in <module>
    import scipy.ndimage
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/__init__.py", line 70, in <module>
    from numpy import show_config as show_numpy_config
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 153, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .npyio import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import format
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 141, in <module>
    import io
  File "/tmp/rm_me/io.py", line 1, in <module>
    import scipy.ndimage
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/ndimage/__init__.py", line 172, in <module>
    from .filters import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/ndimage/filters.py", line 37, in <module>
    from scipy.misc import doccer
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/misc/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from .common import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/misc/common.py", line 10, in <module>
    from numpy import exp, log, asarray, arange, newaxis, hstack, product, array, \
ImportError: cannot import name exp
```

Is this a bug in `SciPy`, or am I using Python wrong?

**Update**: I think less surprising behavior would be if `import mod2` in `mod1` resolved paths relative to `mod1` rather than relative to whomever imported `mod1`.

Comment: This isn't a bug in SciPy; it's just how Python imports work. That being said, I'm not sure what the workaround is besides calling your module something else.

Comment: Run `python --version` and see what you get.

Comment: @user2357112 2.7.6 (Ubuntu-14.04's native)

Comment: It's not a NumPy or SciPy submodule you're hiding; if that were the case, it would find the submodule. What you're hiding is the [Python standard library `io` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html); you'll need to name your module something else, or create a package so your files don't all live at top-level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using python wrong.

Before you create any top-level python module or package, you should make sure there isn't already a module or package by that name.

The best solution here is to not use top-level modules, and instead put everything in a single top-level package (i.e. directory with an `__init__.py` file) named after your project.

To check if a top-level module or package exists, you could try `import`ing it in the interpreter, or running `pydoc name` from the shell.

---

It is worth noting that there is a very similar error that can happen that is not your fault, if a package uses absolute-style import syntax to perform a relative import. This "feature" is removed in Python3.

Comment: What about if later a module/package is added that conflicts with your (top-level) name?

Comment: @JoshB In that case, none of your dependencies will be importing your name yet.

Answer (score 5):

The simple fix is to avoid naming your module `io`, because it's conflicting with a core library module name.

It's not really a bug in numpy, but user error: just as we shouldn't use `list` as a variable name because it's shadowing the builtin `list` name, we shouldn't use `io` as a module name because it's shadowing the core library `io` module name.

See this part:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 141, in <module>
    import io
```

Here `numpy` tries to import the [`io` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html).  This is intended to find the stdlib `io` because of the absolute import - a numpy submodule would have been loaded with *relative* import like you can see in the traceback where there is another line beginning `from .npyio import *`.

Of course your own `io.py` module is found first, because in the current working directory is generally the first entry in `sys.path`.  Whoops!